# What is the right definition of a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I've seen this in all introductory courses on graphs, but every time it bugs me  : the definition of a cycle is usually wrong.
In the last course I have seen they define paths in the obvious way, adding edges inbetween vertices.
Then they say " a cycle is a non-trivial path whose first and last vertices are the same, but no other vertex is repeated" : but obviously this is wrong, since if there's an edge $\{a,b\}$, then the sequence $(a, \{a,b\}, b,\{a,b\}, a)$ is a non trivial path whose first and last vertices are the same, but no other vertex is repeated.

Now what's the proper definition of cycle ? The only way I can see this definition being correct is if "non-trivial" includes the example I gave. But then shouldn't the course mention it, as usually "trivial" means "with one element" or something along those lines ?

Comment: The definition of path you have should include that all edges are distinct.

Comment: Well in the course I'm currently reading they've introduced "backwalks", which are subpaths of the form  I have presented,  and they say that removing them gives a "reduced path", but they didn't say that cycles had to be reduced so what you're saying, although coherent, doesn't seem consistent with the course in question

Comment: I've read through many graph theory books, and I don't recall ever seeing those terms used. So it's probably worth just asking the prof about it (and let us know their answer!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cycle is either:

- a simple graph (= no double edges, no loops) with 1 component and all vertices having vertex degree 2
- a graph with 2 vertices and two edges between them
- a graph with 1 vertex and a loop